# DIfferent behavior on two installations of a Joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

I have just copied a Joomla app to my new computer (Macbook Air). I installed php with http://php-osx.liip.ch/ and I have the same version of MySQL.

In this new installation, I keep getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /Volumes/Joomla/soccerapp/plugins/content/collapsible/helper.php on line 141
```

That is exactly the last line of the file.

I go to that file and I don't see anything that might be wrong, except that I see lines that look like this `<?=`

I am concerned that the parser is not acting the same way in this system, but I am lost on what to do. I have copied the php.ini file from one system to the other, and I keep getting the error. How should I proceed?

Comment: Oh, so many possibilities.  Different version of PHP? Not having PHP "short tags" turned on? Hard to know without *lots* more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?=` is a special form of a shortcut for the php opening tag. Most likely you forgot to enable it on the new system. Look for the 'short_open_tag' configuration option.